# Converting Types

Tags: scala, type-conversion

I was trying to convert an object with Object type into FontUIResource type. In Java, it would be

```
FontUIResource font = (FontUIResource)value
```

How would I do that in Scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can say `value.asInstanceOf[FontUIResource]`, or you can use a match-case block:

```
value match{
  case f:FontUIResource => 
    //do something with f, which is safely cast as a FontUIResource
  case _ => 
    //handle the case when it's not the desired type
}
```

Comment: The kind of `case` illustrated here is essentially syntactic sugar for an `isInstanceOf` / `asInstanceOf` pair with the casted value assigned to the match variable (`f` in this example). It should be clear why the `match` form is preferable to the is / as code.

Answer (score 3):

You mean casting, not Boxing and Unboxing, since that applies to primitive values. `value.asInstanceOf[FountUIResource]` is the way to cast this in Scala.

Comment: Primitive values, rather than numeric.